# extjs status bar and validation checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, extjs

I'm using the sample extjs status bar, the one with the word count demo. I set the name and id of the text area within my JS file to match the other form items on the page (in this case something like, user_description and user[description]) However when it throws back an error with validation of the description being over my limit, it "remembers" (as in repopulates) all fields except for my extjs status bar file. How can I get this to work with the rails default error validation?